# How to get custom count of rows in a table in HBase shell

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How can I get the count of rows in a table with respect to a column value which is not empty in HBase shell?

The query I tried gives the total count of rows in that table, instead of filtering with respect to a column value not empty in a time-stamp range or in a specific date:

```
count '/data_table', {INTERVAL => 1000000, COLUMNS => ['cf1:c1','cf2:c2'], FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('cf2','c2',=, 'binary:')", TIMERANGE => [1472034600000,1472063399000]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apache-drill](https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-hbase/)
 to query HBase. It will Definitely solve your problem.
 I'm not sure about your HBase query.